# SQL Server Developer - Free

Tags: sql-server

Can I use SQL Server Free Developer software for my Development and Test machines?  Do we need to license these servers or can I install the free SQL Software?  These would only be used for testing/development purposes.

Thank you..

Comment: I'm afraid licensing questions are considered off-topic; have you tried contacting the vendor?

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server development and testing environments, Microsoft does not charge you for [licenses](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing) and you can test all available features.

> Full-featured version of SQL Server software that allows developers to
>   cost-effectively build, test, and demonstrate applications based on
>   SQL Server software.

In addition, you can also perform the free installation of the SQL Server Express version.

> Free entry-level database that's ideal for learning, as well as building desktop and small server data-driven applications of up to 10 GB.

However, express version has some limitations and does not contain all available [features](https://expressdb.io/sql-server-express-feature-comparison/).

You can read some about it at these links:

1. [Licensing SQL Server for Development and Test](https://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/licensing/2013/06/licensing-sql-server-development-and-test)
2. [SQL Server licensing for test environments RRS feed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9dc59919-3cea-47e7-ab53-b306be1d2178/sql-server-licensing-for-test-environments?forum=sqlgetstarted)

However, it is always wise to consult your Microsoft sales representative because license rules may change.